# Facebook apk for emulator constantly crashing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Facebook apk delivered with sdk 4.1.0 doesn't not work in emulators where it supposed to work(sdk emulator and genymotion)

It always crashes with the same exception

```
05-08 08:42:42.022    3279-3279/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could find DSO to load: libbreakpad.so
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(SoLoader.java:179)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(SoLoader.java:144)
        at com.facebook.breakpad.BreakpadManager.a(BreakpadManager.java:55)
        at com.facebook.breakpad.BreakpadManager.b(BreakpadManager.java:78)
        at com.facebook.breakpad.BreakpadManager.a(BreakpadManager.java:82)
        at com.facebook.katana.app.FacebookApplication.b(FacebookApplication.java:169)
        at com.facebook.base.app.DelegatingApplication.attachBaseContext(DelegatingApplication.java:62)
        at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:146)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:983)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4124)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Can you try the newest version v4.1.2? If it is still ctrashing, you could file a bug report at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @curioushikhov did you fix the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your avd image from x86 to Arm.

It should work with you now.

Comment: I receive the same crash and error message when using an ARM emulator.

Comment: @Benjamin Same error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could find DSO to load: libbreakpad.so" ??